# How to deserialize this xml?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I have the following xml I want to deserialize into object. I'm using C#.

```
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1251'?>
    <RootElement>
      <AnotherRoot>
        <parameter name="param1">
          <value>"12"</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="param2">
          <value>"John"</value>
        </parameter>
      </AnotherRoot>
    </RootElement>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could opt with the following

1. Save the XML as a file
2. Generate an XSD from the XML using either Visual Studio's XML tools or the xsd.exe from the Visual Studio Command line located in the Start -> Programs -> Visual Studio 2008/2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> *Command Line
3. Generate a serializable class using the save xsd.exe but now on the .xsd and with the /c argument
4. Include the Generated code inside your solution
5. Inside your code

   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourRootElement));
   YourRootElement deserializedObject = (YourRootElement)serializer.DeSerialize(File.Open(yourXmlFileLocation);

Now you can work with it in a familiar C# object oriented way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 4, you could go for the `dynamic` route. See here for an example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/04/dynamic-xml-reader-with-c-and-net-4-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need an class to deserialize it into.

What this class looks like and how it relates to your XML is something *you* need to decide.

Look at the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and the different attributes ([`DataContractAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`DataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx)) it uses to serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/07/make-your-xml-stronglytyped-because-you-can-and-its-easy for a nice overview of how to use `xsd.exe` to generate a schema definition from an XML file, and from there generate a class that you can deserialize into easily.